# Cordova Android Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I upgraded today to the newest Cordova - 5.4.1. App on iOS kept working just fine but not on Android. All requests were returning 404 error, so I dig into the topic and found out that I need "cordova-plugin-whitelist". I installed it and added

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

to the header of index.html as well as `<access origin="*" /><allow-navigation href="*"/>` to config.xml

and now every request to external world is returning "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

In AndroidManifest.xml I have those two lines so I guess it's not a problem with Internet access.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`

I went through many questions on SO related to cordova-plugin-whitelist but nothing seems to work

My config.xml
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="app" version="1.1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>app</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <platform name="ios">...splash screens and icons</platform>
    <platform name="android">...splash screens and icons</platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
    <feature name="phonegap-parse-plugin">
        <param name="id" value="org.apache.cordova.core.parseplugin" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/fastrde/phonegap-parse-plugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)">
        <param name="id" value="nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Toast">
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-x-toast" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Cordova SMS Plugin">
        <param name="id" value="com.cordova.plugins.sms" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin.git" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="OpenTokCordovaPlugin">
        <param name="id" value="com.tokbox.cordova.opentok" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/doxyme/cordova-plugin-opentok" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

```

Comment: Are you using the cordova-plugin-whitelist and have you configured Content-Security-Policy ? What version of cordova were you previously using ?

Comment: i have faced this problem. Find out that it happened when internet is slow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have no idea what the issue was but restarting device resolved it. Nothing related to the app, just the phone had difficulties with connecting to Internet even though it was connected to Wi-Fi and signal strength seemed to be on max.

Comment: Ha ok. Indeed it would have been strange that `cordova-whitelist-plugin` was involved, as `<allow-navigation href="*" />` with an empty *Content-Security-Policy* should let everything pass through. Glad you solved your issue

Comment: I have <allow-navigation href="*" /> with an empty Content-Security-Policy, it didnt work until I rsetarted the device.

I can't believe that restarting the device also solved my problem.

Comment: upped because I had the same problem because I forgot to enable wi-fi.

Comment: Sad... it worked. Now, how can I explain it to my users?!? How can they imagine that if the app is not working then they have to restart it???

Comment: -_- ...really android?? ... a lot of wasted time figuring this out. @Pawel thanks! Was trying to get this to work with dnsmasq on the mac ..and this post saved me.

Answer (score 4):

In your app's 'config.xml',  place only this:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

And remove what you added to your index.html header. 
Then if it still doesn't work that means your problem is not related to the **whitelist plugin**.

I used this plugin in different Android projects and never had to do more than this to allow my app to communicate with the back-end.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. I edited my question and added config.xml

Comment: Ah, I skipped the part "and remove what you added you index.html". When I do that I'm getting "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin." and requests are returning exactly the same error "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Comment: Sorry didn't know about that, this seems to be a relatively new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue where we received the "Failed to load resource net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error on two different systems from the android emulator running in HAXM using Cordova 6.4.0 and the version 25 (7.1.1) android SDK. Simply removing and adding the whilelist plugin resolved our issue **without** changing any configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and nothing seemed to solve... And I figured out that in my case was the splashscreen image size that was too big (about 3.2MB)... I used [this website](https://tinypng.com/) to compress the file and then worked.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Device seems to resolve this problem for me locally, but this piece of work always comes back to me from support. So would like to have a fix for the solution not a workaround.

The whitelist plugin also has [Content Security Policy](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) declarations:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

This seems to have resolved the issue for me, but only time will tell as I can never get this issue to replicate on demand.

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the mentioned solutions worked. What worked for me was adding the plugin directly from the repo:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --force
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

If the problem persists you can go ahead and remove and add the platform again:

```
cordova platform save
cordova platform rm <platform>
cordova platform add <platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to send requests yet you are offline, try to check internet connection.